# Strange error in python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

The following code is to find the mean of a given input set of numbers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Enter some integers")
count = 0
total = 0
while True:
    line = input("integer: ")
    if (line):
        try:
            number = int(line)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
            continue
        total += number
        count += 1
        #print("Post",line)
    else:
        break
if count:
    print('Count is ',count ,'Total is ',total,'Mean is ',total/count)
```

However, whenever I run the program, the even numbered input gives me an error even though I enter a number. The following is the sample output.

```
Enter some integers
integer: 4
integer: 5
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'integer: 5'
integer: 5
integer: 6
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'integer: 6'
integer:
Count is  2 Total is  9 Mean is  4.5
```

However, this code works fine if I uncomment the line before the else: statement. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the same code that produces this error?

Comment: You may want to try and catch for PEBKAC :) It seems to work fine. I tested it under Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 21 2011, 01:55:53).

Comment: Tested you code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a question of cut and paste.

The line

```
number = int(line)
```

Generates the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'integer: 6'
```

This means that the line

```
line = input("integer: ")
```

Must have recieved the input:

```
'integer: 6'
```

And the only way it could have recieved this, is if that is what you inputted.
Obviously, you would not be so daft as to **type** in "integer: 6". Hence the only reason this happens is that you have cut and pasted your previous input without noticing that you got to much when you copied, which is something that happens to me all the time.

Comment: Thanks all, it looks like the problem was with the IDE (Komodo Edit). I ran the code in terminal and it worked.